# How to append byte array to file?

Tags: vb.net

I want to write a `byte array` to the end of an existing file. How to append byte array to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution. Just use the following sub and provide the parameters as required:

Parameters description:

**FilepathToAppendTo** is the filepath you need to append the byte array

**Content** is your byte array

```
Private Sub AppendByteToDisk(ByVal FilepathToAppendTo As String, ByRef Content() As Byte)
    Dim s As New System.IO.FileStream(FilepathToAppendTo, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite)
    s.Write(Content, 0, Content.Length)
    s.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `System.IO.FileStream`  class methods. Open/create a FileStream in append file mode.

```
System.IO.FileStream(filename,System.IO.FileMode.Append)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim bufData As Byte()

' write the entire buffer in one line of code
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("BinaryFile.DAT", bufData, append := True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Assumptions.

- You want to use UTF8 encoding.

```cs
using( var stream = File.AppendText(@"D:\test.txt"))
{
    stream.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString( b ) );
}
```

VB Version:

```vb
Using stream = File.AppendText("D:\test.txt")
    stream.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b))
End Using
```

Comment: If his question is explicitly tagged "vb.net", why do you assume he is after C# code?

Comment: For some reason, formatting didnt work on the code. Excuse my brevity.

Comment: I will excuse your brevity, but not the content of your answer. ;-) You are converting the byte array to an ASCII-encoded string, and then convert this back into UTF-8 (see the documentation of AppendText). That's completely unnecessary. Just open the file with `new FileStream` and write the byte array directly with `FileStream.Write`. No need to do any (re-)encoding.

Comment: It's not just unnecessary, it's wrong. If there are any bytes above 127, the bytes written to the file will be different that what is in the array.

Comment: I had my mouse over for a second & method signature poped up on the method and I saw UTF-8 from the corner of my eye whilst typing and dont know why I decided to write ASCII in assumptions.

Comment: Interesting though, why would File.AppendText not accept the encoding from the caller and why it defaults to UTF8, wonder what the design decision was ?

Comment: How could it accept “encoding from the caller”? `String` is always encoded using UTF16. And your code still doesn't work properly, try saving an array contain just the byte 254. It is saved as four bytes. That's because converting byte array to string just so that it can be saved to a file doesn't make any sense.